# I am trying to extract a "a" tagged element inside a "div" but its not working

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

[See image for the element i want to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeHys.png)

I have tried doc.select(a.jsname) but its not working

and extracting element by class name "rg_1" is also not working.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the html as text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Have you tried, just to select `a` or  `div`. Then you should get plenty of results (if everything else is OK).

For your issue, all of the following selectors should work:

- `a.rg_1`  (<a>-tag with class='rg_1')
- `.rg_1`    (any tag with class='rg_1')
- `a[jsname=hSRGPd]`  (<a>-Tag with attribute jsname equals 'hSRGPd')
- `[jsname]`  (any tag having an attribute jsname with any value)

Depending on what you want, there might be more specific selectors. But these should be a good starting point.

See https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax for more details on how to write selectors.